# Idea on how to make video maker website?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to create website that create video and user can share that website in any social site.

(example sites:

1. flixpress.com
2. studio.stupeflix.com
3. www.photodex.com
4. www.picovico.com  )

this type of website i want to create.After long research and come to conclusion to use imagemagick and ffmpeg for my website.I learn the basic of the ffmpeg and imagemagick.
SO I create code like this 
for text overlay in ffmpeg i create code like this

```
   ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Vera.ttf: \
        text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black: \
        x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2" -codec:a copy output.flv
```

and for imagemagick use convert to make pics and make slideshow with ffmpeg code.

```
 shell_exec(" ffmpeg -framerate 1*10 -i %d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out1.mp4");
```

This code works fine.No error, nothing.
But the output video does not have the quality that i wanted.
My question is that for create website like i mentioned above.Am i using the right software (ffmpeg and imagemagick).what software or code this type of website used? Any idea? any opensource software or program for this?
I am just newbie and try to learn the things.
Please provide guidance on this what i am doing wrong.Just give the software name of programe which is used for this type of website. I can go through by myself. Please Give some idea on this.

Comment: You're not gonna find premade software for this. Creating websites this advanced involves learning a lot and coding them yourself. You could use these programs behind the scenes, but you need to learn about web developement before making a website. Even then, a website like this is a nontrivial project, it may not be the greatest way to learn.

Comment: can you provide any name of such software .Life is long i can try to learn.

Comment: I don't know about software, but if you want to learn about web development [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/) is helpful.

Comment: I know basic of the web development i konw html and php.

Comment: I do not know which software or luggage used for this

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for then. If you want web app frameworks for PHP, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP_2) has a list. You'll still have to code your own site though.

Comment: I want the name of software which make video

Comment: That's rather subjective. There are many different programs for this, including the ones which you have used. Pick whichever you like the most.

Comment: I only know ffmpeg.provide other please